# Scipy.optimize: minimize function yields error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to optimize forecast parameters with `scipy.optimize`. I followed tutorial and also found some nice example here on stackoverflow but I am facing an issue that I cannot resolve. I am starting to wonder whether using pandas is a poor choice with scipy?

I have set up my code as follow:

```
import simpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import pandas as pd
import statistics as stat
import math as m
#from sklearn.grid_search import ParameterGrid
from scipy.optimize import minimize

###dataframe for the simulation

df = pd.read_csv('simulation_df_data_2018_2.csv')
with pd.option_context("max_rows", None,"max_columns", None):
    print(df.head())


for i in df.index:
    alpha = 0.2
    beta = 0.3
    
    x = np.array([alpha, beta])

 
    def holts(x):

        LO = np.int(df['average_demand'].loc[i])
        print(type(LO))

        TO = ((df['m2'].loc[i] - df['m3'].loc[i]) + (df['m1'].loc[i] - df['m2'].loc[i])) / 2
        L1 = round(x[0] * df['m3'].loc[i] + (1 - x[0]) * (
                LO + TO))
        T1 = x[1] * (L1 - LO) + (1 - x[1]) * TO

        L2 = round(x[0] * df['m2'].loc[i] + (1 - x[0]) * (
                L1 + T1))
        T2 = x[1] * (L2 - L1) + (1 - x[1]) * T1
        L3 = round(x[0] * df['m1'].loc[i] + (1 - x[0]) * (
                L2 + T2))
        T3 = beta * (L3 - L2) + (1 - beta) * T2
        LT1 = round(L3 + 1 * T3)
        MSE = ((df['m3'].loc[i] - L1) + (df['m2'].loc[i] - L2) + (
                df['m2'].loc[i] - L3)) ** 2 / 3

        return MSE
    #print(holts(x))

    x0 = [0.1,0.1]

    result = minimize(holts, x0, bounds=[(0,1),(0,1)], method="SLSQP")
    print(result)
    print(x)
```

and df looks like this:

```
     m1     m2     m3     m4     m5     m6     m7     m8     m9    m10    m11  \
0   0.0    8.0    2.0    0.0   14.0    0.0    5.0    2.0    4.0    4.0   10.0   
1   4.0   55.0    2.0   72.0   38.0   87.0  113.0    2.0    0.0  165.0    2.0   
2  18.0   34.0    6.0   63.0   14.0   18.0   33.0   35.0   51.0    0.0   24.0   
3   0.0   21.0    3.0   10.0   15.0    0.0   32.0    1.0    3.0   17.0    0.0   
4  96.0  106.0  237.0  136.0  138.0  116.0  167.0  158.0  110.0  115.0  161.0   

     m12   m13   m14   m15   m16    m17   m18   m19   m20    m21    m22  \
0    0.0   6.0  10.0   0.0   2.0    2.0  17.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0   
1   35.0   7.0  88.0   6.0   3.0  103.0  18.0  59.0   6.0   20.0  152.0   
2    6.0   5.0  99.0   7.0  17.0   15.0   8.0   3.0  21.0    6.0    4.0   
3   30.0   5.0  88.0   1.0   6.0   10.0   9.0  17.0   9.0    0.0    1.0   
4  116.0  77.0  48.0  96.0  69.0   77.0  96.0  74.0  94.0  101.0  115.0   

     m23    m24  average_demand  low_demand  high_demand  
0    0.0    0.0        3.583333         0.0         17.0  
1    6.0    0.0       43.458333         0.0        165.0  
2   14.0   12.0       21.375000         0.0         99.0  
3    0.0    0.0       11.583333         0.0         88.0  
4  158.0  167.0      117.833333        48.0        237.0
```

I am very confused about the error I keep getting, here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/simul/forecast_holts_alpha.py", line 121, in <module>
    result = minimize(holts, x0, args= coef_list,bounds=[(0,1),(0,1)], method="SLSQP")
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 618, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 399, in _minimize_slsqp
    fx = func(x)
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/simul/forecast_holts_alpha.py", line 63, in holts
    LO = np.int(df['average_demand'].loc[i])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I don't get why this error is popping up there, especially because if I search the type of LO I get this:

```
print(type(LO))

<class 'int'>
```

I am not an experience programmer so I struggle to figure out what is going on, any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

```
   fun: 56.333333333333336
     jac: array([0., 0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 4
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.1, 0.1])
[0.2,0.3]
```

OUTPUT looks like this but does not seem to be optimizing anything

Comment: I think [docs for `scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) can be helpful. Your `holts` function signature is not matched with the doc, which should be `fun(x, *args) -> float`. Since `x0 = [0.1, 0.1]` in your code, I think `x` should be 1-D array with shape (2,).

Comment: thank you for the link, it helped, but I don't get much out of "where x is an 1-D array with shape (n,) and args is a tuple of the fixed parameters needed to completely specify the function." beside that x needs to be an array and not a dataframe, would you be able to tell me what X needs to be?

Comment: In the function signiture `fun(x, *args) -> float`, `x` should be the *variables* of the function you want to minimize. In your code, you want to minimize `holts` function and `holts(df, coef_list)` function has `df` in the place for the variables `x`, which seems to be wrong. For what *variables* do you want to minimize `holts` function? Your `holts` function seems to have *no variables*.

Comment: I am trying to minimize MSE by optimizing the variable alpha and beta. If i understand you, x needs to be an array with alpha and beta?

Comment: Yes. If `alpha` and `beta` is the variable, `x` needs to be an array with `alpha` and `beta`.

Comment: i just tried doing this, I'll update my post but the thing is that it does not seem optimize anything, i must be setting something wrong

Comment: there is no `x` in your function `holts`. So `scipy` can't minimize `x`.

Comment: i updated my code above to reflect your suggestion, however it still does not optimize

Comment: I posted an answer. Please try it and let me know if it does what you want or something.

Comment: As I commented at the code in my answer, the line `LT1 = round(L3 + 1 * T3)` does nothing. Maybe there's some mistakes?

Comment: its the predicted value, optimizing the parameters for the forecast on existing data (LO, L1, L2, L3, etc...) calibrate the forecast so that Lt1 is the most accurate possible. in fact Lt1 is used later in the program I am making

Comment: Oh, I see. And the numbers in `df` are the coefficients?

Comment: m1 m2 m3 are historical demand values. So its like we are calibrating the model for 3 months to make a prediction for one period ahead. x[0] is telling whether we give importance to older historical data point or recent ones, beta does the same thing about T, which is the trend factor in the forecast

Comment: And when we track the variables in `MSE`, it does not contain `x[1]`, only contains `x[0]`. Is it intended?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, sorry. `MSE` also contains `x[1]`.

Comment: so they are not contained but are still used in the result because L1, L2, L3 include alpha and T (which include x1). I feel like the setup is correct there I don't why its not optimizing

Comment: Is `round` function intended? I think `round` function is the reason the `minimize` is not working.

Comment: I just tried without round() and it seems that you are right!

Comment: Yeah. I think `round` creates many plateaus on the graph of the function `holts`. So `minimize` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know about what your code is exactly doing, I can't tell whether the following code is doing right. But just for a guide to how to use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function, it should be something like the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize

df = pd.read_csv('simulation_df_data_2018_2.csv')

for i in df.index:
    # Since you said "alpha" and "beta" are the variable of "holts" function
    # I changed all "alpha" and "beta" to "x[0]" and "x[1]" respectively.
    def holts(x):
        LO = np.int(df['average_demand'].loc[i])
        TO = ((df['m2'].loc[i] - df['m3'].loc[i]) + (df['m1'].loc[i] - df['m2'].loc[i])) / 2
        L1 = x[0] * df['m3'].loc[i] + (1 - x[0]) * (LO + TO)
        T1 = x[1] * (L1 - LO) + (1 - x[1]) * TO
        L2 = x[0] * df['m2'].loc[i] + (1 - x[0]) * (L1 + T1)
        T2 = x[1] * (L2 - L1) + (1 - x[1]) * T1
        L3 = x[0] * df['m1'].loc[i] + (1 - x[0]) * (L2 + T2)
        MSE = ((df['m3'].loc[i] - L1) + (df['m2'].loc[i] - L2) + (df['m2'].loc[i] - L3)) ** 2 / 3
        return MSE


    x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1])  # initial guess for the points "x" which "holts(x)" attains its minimum.

    result = minimize(holts, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1)], method="SLSQP", options={'disp': True})
    print(result)
    print()
```

which prints

```
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 16.921875002444228
            Iterations: 5
            Function evaluations: 15
            Gradient evaluations: 5
     fun: 16.921875002444228
     jac: array([ 8.06808472e-04, -6.23427415e+00])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 15
     nit: 5
    njev: 5
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.75000606, 1.        ])

Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 3.0792324286388828e-09
            Iterations: 7
            Function evaluations: 24
            Gradient evaluations: 7
     fun: 3.0792324286388828e-09
     jac: array([-0.00833083, -0.00081578])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 24
     nit: 7
    njev: 7
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.1495232 , 0.25665903])

Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 1.9951658230345873e-10
            Iterations: 9
            Function evaluations: 32
            Gradient evaluations: 9
     fun: 1.9951658230345873e-10
     jac: array([0.03791677, 0.00858221])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 32
     nit: 9
    njev: 9
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.37155192, 0.19218713])

Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 114.53090716252409
            Iterations: 11
            Function evaluations: 37
            Gradient evaluations: 11
     fun: 114.53090716252409
     jac: array([ 3.06129456e-04, -3.04457455e+01])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 37
     nit: 11
    njev: 11
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.7171298, 1.       ])

Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 33.333333333333336
            Iterations: 2
            Function evaluations: 6
            Gradient evaluations: 2
     fun: 33.333333333333336
     jac: array([-403.33331966,   -0.        ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1., 1.])
```

**UPDATE**:
It seems that the `round` function is the reason `minimize` function is not working, since `round` function would create many plateaus on the graph of `holts` function. I removed the `round` functions and updated the result printed.

Comment: that does not make the trick, x being the optimized values are always the same as the orginal ([0.1, 0.1]) for me and go to 1 for you as you initianilized them with [30,50] so they go to the upper bound. I am not sure what is going on

Comment: Oh, right. My guess `[30, 50]` is beyond the upper bound, lol. I should fix it.